# How to give notification after location.reload();

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am working on a code where I need to display a popup or an alert after I reload the page like this

```
 location.reload();
```

Can any one let me know how to give condition after the page is loaded.

Comment: then you go for cookie in javascript

Comment: you can always carry that information in url as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page does not know if a `location.reload()` was called.

You can set the value in a cookie, localstorage, or pass the value in the URL before calling `location.reload()`. Then check if it exists every time the page is loaded.

Answer (score 2):

Set some variable like `isreloaded` to localstorage and check the value everytime the page loads to show the alert.

You can also use `cookies` as pointed out by @Romeo Gresta